# Mass emailing - maximum recipients problem

Tags: joomla-2.5, emails, smtp, jmail

We have a client who would like users to be able to send a mass email to other registered users on the site. We have got this working perfect using Joomla's `JMail` class which gets all users' email addresses from the database and sets it as the recipient. The problem being is that the server the site is currently hosted on only allows 40 recipients per email.

Moving to a new server **is** an option but firstly I would like to know if there is any way of dealing with the email the same way SMTP work which is, it keeps trying to send the email every time it fails, until it is successfully sent.

I have looked at the Joomla API but the SMTP method uses the settings from the global configuration.

Can anyone please enlighten me as the best way to approach this issue?

Comment: What if you would write a function to group the recipients by 40 and then run the send email ?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I will definitely give that a go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it were me, I'd do this:

1. Sign up for Mandrill (made by the MailChimp people). You get the first 12,000 message for free. Sign up here: https://mandrill.com
2. Get the CMandrill component from CompoJoom for free. Get it here: [CMandrill](https://compojoom.com/joomla-extensions/mandrill-transactional-emails-made-easy)
3. Follow all the CMandrill instructions.

It bypasses the entire Joomla mail system and sends everything through Mandrill. At 12k messages a month, it likely won't ever cost you anything. I use this on several sites and it's great. You can even set up templates and brand all your emails without hacking the language files in Joomla.

You can also use something like ACY with Mandrill if you wanted to do fancy eblasts.

Comment: Checked your links, got a question: Is this service working for front-end users, allowing them to exchange emails with others?

Comment: It simply replaces the path that ANY joomla originated email takes and sends it to Mandrill to be sent out. So if your plugin/extension uses the built in mail function (not its own mail settings) it should go out through Mandrill instead. If your extension has its OWN mail settings, you can just use the Mandrill SMTP credentials and send it that way (without the CMandrill component). We use ACY mailer that way with Mandrill. We also use it with CMandrill (with jomsocial installed as well) and it works fine for all messages.