# Activation email not sent via localhost?

Tags: joomla-3.x

when i try to register from the **front-end of Joomla**, its displayed that the activation email has been sent but actually there is no email sent. i have tried this before but on a Web host and it works fine on any Web host. For now i need to test **user registration on LOCALHOST**?

*I am using PHP MAIL, don't know anything about SMTP config?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Gmail as your mailer, below is the working SMTP configuration needed.

Go to `Global Configuration -> Server -> Mail Settings`

`Send Mail` : `Yes`

`Mailer` : `SMTP`

`From Email` : `youremail@gmail.com`

`From Name` : `name_goes_here`

`SMTP Authentication` : `Yes`

`SMTP Security`  : `SSL`

`SMTP Port` : `465`

`SMTP Username` : `youremail@gmail.com`

`SMTP Password` : `your_gmail_account_password`

`SMTP Host` : `smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: This would also work:
http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/mass-emailing-maximum-recipients-problem/1117#1117

Comment: This looks like a valuable/related reference: https://www.cloudaccess.net/joomla-knowledgebase/107-joomla-3-1/global-configuration/559-joomla-smtp-mail-settings.html