# Joomla contact mail error "SMTP connect() failed"

Tags: localhost, xampp

I am running Joomla on my computer (windows 8.1) over xampp.
I created a contact page following [this](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla-video/contact-form.htm) guide but when I try to send an email I get

> Notice SMTP connect() failed

I get to global settings and folloing [this](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1146/activation-email-not-sent-via-localhost?newreg=3e7eaa9091fd4956abac86246fc37375) guide I used my gmail.
Any suggestions?

I am totally new to the world of Joomla and generally to the creations of websites!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

By default, Xampp doesn't support a mail service which is what the `Notice SMTP connect() failed` error is associated with.

If you feel comfortable enough setting it up, a good post was written here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost

Else you will have to put your site on a live hosting environment to test your contact form

Comment: I couldn't setting it up, I tried this kind of guides step by step but nothing! I also tried stunnel and again nothing! I guess I do something wrong. If someone else made it on win 8.1 and xampp 5.6.11 please let me know the steps! Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue but i was 100% sure that is was setup properly.  Finally i discovered that it was my antivirus app creating a problem. I have added exception and solved smtp connect issue.